# Where and how should I ask about sourcing parts?

Tags: discussion

I know this isn't meant to be a marketplace or ad site, but I have some very specific parts that I'm looking for that aren't carried by Arrow, Mouser, DigiKey, etc...the big players. Google searches have come up empty-handed unless I want to buy a shipping container full of them direct from China.

I'm looking for recommendations about perhaps some smaller, specialty online retailers that I don't know about, suggestions for substitutions that may be more readily available, and/or tips on some alternate places to look (e.g., a fuse may be hard to find @ Mouser because every auto repair shop has them...)

One - Is this an appropriate question to EE, and Two - What are some suggestions for phrasing so it doesn't get deleted as soliciting recommendations for commercial ventures?

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/761/142 http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/375/142

Comment: You might try usernet sci.electronics.design

Answer (score 1):

No, those types of questions are not appropriate here.  They just don't work well with the Q&A format of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Find the vendor's distributor and/or representative covering your area. Contact them.

Alternate [Octopart](http://octopart.com/) has a pretty good parts search engine.

Comment: If he says he's "looking for them" then "find them" is not really a good answer.

Comment: @BrianCarlton that would be great if I knew a manufacturer. Let's say I'm looking for a .33uF capacitor (or something else in a wierd, nonstandard size/rating/performance spec). Who's the manufacturer? Lots of times I can't find ANYthing. If, however, someone knows of oddsizecapacitors.com and I don't, I'd love to have that information so I can continue my research. When I know a manufacturer, I can at least continue my research, to the point where I have the sales rep contact the last client who bought a 5000pc reel of part X to see if they'd sell me one. BTW, they shipped it to me for free.

Comment: @dwwilson66 You could use this forum to ask for tips on using a standard part in place of the 0.33uF cap or whatever weird part to get the same functionality. Generally, if you can't find a specific part there's a good reason for it.